# Strange issue with terminal getting messed up: vim/coc-nvim/golang/gopls/zsh/gpg

Tags: go, ssh, vim, zsh, gpg-agent

I am having a very annoying issue and I don't know exactly what's the problem. It could have loads of possible causes, so please bear with me trying to fix this.

I use `vim` to code. I use `coc.nvim` as plugin for code completion and navigation. Languageserver is set to `golang` and I use this config:

```
{
  "suggest.noselect": false,
  "diagnostic.errorSign": "✘",
  "diagnostic.warningSign": "!",
  "diagnostic.infoSign": "?",
  "diagnostic.checkCurrentLine": true,
  "coc.preferences.currentFunctionSymbolAutoUpdate": true,
  "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": [
    "javascript",
    "html",
    "json",
    "css",
    "scss",
    "go"
  ],
  "languageserver": {
    "golang": {
      "command": "gopls",
      "rootPatterns": [
        "go.work",
        "go.mod",
        ".vim/",
        ".git/",
        ".hg/"
      ],
      "trace.server": "verbose",
      "filetypes": [
        "go"
      ],
      "initializationOptions": {
        "usePlaceholders": true
      }
    },
    "golangci-lint-languageserver": {
      "command": "golangci-lint-langserver",
      "filetypes": [
        "go"
      ],
      "initializationOptions": {
        "command": [
          "golangci-lint",
          "run",
          "--out-format",
          "json"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What's happening is that apparently randomly, if I open a `.go` file (it seems to happen mostly with go files which import libraries), **my terminal gets irreparably messed up**, usually completely messing up my editing session, not knowing if I was able to save or not my current buffer. Have to kill the shell!

Now, this started happening after at work we had been urged to use ssh keys stored on a yubikey. For this to work, we had to reconfigure the `gpg-agent`.

This is it's config:

```
enable-ssh-support
ttyname $GPG_TTY
default-cache-ttl 60
max-cache-ttl 60
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```

What I think is happening, is that during my vim editing session some ssh connection is opened (presumably to download github libs?). At the bottom appears something which looks like a prompt to enter the ssh key - but at this point I have lost the control of the terminal. Nothing works.

I think that is `pinentry-curses` which triggers that. But why is an ssh connection triggered and why does that mess up my terminal?

I run ubuntu 20.04 with i3, zsh with `oh-my-zsh` and `powerlevel10k`. I load these plugins for `zsh`, including the `ssh-agent` one which I think is needed:

```
plugins=(git z zsh-autosuggestions vi-mode ssh-agent)
```

I am really annoyed, any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: workaround: use `/usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2` for `pinentry-program`. However, that's kinda weird I would like to avoid having to spin up a GUI thing if I am in the terminal....

Comment: Use Coc's dedicated support channels.